# How to read or parse .mobi file on iOS

Tags: ios, parsing, mobipocket

I'm developing an iOS reader App and I want to support the .mobi file by Amazon.I search but find few things about parse .mobi file on iOS.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mobipocket e-book format is based on the Open eBook standard using XHTML and can include JavaScript  and frames. It also supports native SQL queries to be used with embedded databases.

I am not aware of easily adaptable source code (especially for iOS), but here is the format spec, you could try to parse it, though I don't think it will be easy:  http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/MOBI

It might not be elegant but maybe you can use a converter (there are a few links on the page) and try a more public/better supported format instead.